# Css: Wordpress & Boostrap: Styling the Posts Page's featured image

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have been asked to use bootstrap css while creating this custom theme:

http://crippslawtest.co.uk/news/

I have floated everything left (and I mean everything), but whatever I do, the title and excerpt won't bump up besides my featured image(See solicitors image).

I am finding it difficult to think of some sort of css conditional statement so everything aligns whether there is a featured image or not.

How should this be done? How do you write "If there is a featured image, make the title and excerpt have a max width of 300px"? I don't get it and can't find anything relative online.

I created a JS fiddle by copying my Firefox Firebug htmlk and css across, and that works but it doesn't on my page :( :( :(  :

http://jsfiddle.net/pu6t3/

Here is my css:

```
.floatleft, 
.news-page h1, 
.news-page header.entry-header, 
.news-page .entry-content, 
a.post-thumbnail img.attachment-CrippsTheme-full-width, 
.news-page .the-categories {
    float: left;
}
```

And my Wordpress loop:

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) :
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
CrippsTheme_post_thumbnail();
echo '<p class="the-date">';
the_date();
echo '</p>';
//Get the categories
echo '<p class="the-categories">';
$categories = get_the_category();
$separator = ' ';
$output = '';
if($categories){
foreach($categories as $category) {
$output .= '<a class="feedcat" href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'.$separator;
}
echo trim($output, $separator);
}
echo '</p>';
// End of get categories
echo '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="';
the_permalink();
echo '">';
the_title();
echo '</a></h1><br class="c" /><p>';
the_excerpt();
echo '</p>';
echo '<p class="read-more"><a href="';
the_permalink();
echo '">Read More...</a></p><br class="c" />';


endwhile;
CrippsTheme_paging_nav();
else :
get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Here's your first mistake **"I have floated everything left (and I mean everything)"**. Why?

Comment: @Paulie_D I floated everything left because I want my title and excerpt text to go next to my featured image. The only way I can think of is to float left? What did you have in mind? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could show us a reduced case in JSfiddle.

Comment: @Paulie_D I have created a js fiddle, where I copied across my html and css, and the fiddle works ! But mine does not! Very confusing :S http://jsfiddle.net/pu6t3/

Comment: Do I have to write an if else in php for my css? :S

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/pu6t3/1/

add the image at the beginning of the paragraph (before the text, but after the "p" tag) and 
add some styling for the image with some margin so that it is readable.

```
<p class="the-date">

 <a class="post-thumbnail" href="http://crippslawtest.co.uk/top-25-law-firms/">
 <img width="270" height="192" style="float:left;margin:0 25px 0 0;" src="http://crippslawtest.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/featured-one.jpg" class="attachment-CrippsTheme-full-width wp-post-image" alt="featured-one" /></a>
 April 21, 2014

<a class="feedcat" href="http://crippslawtest.co.uk/category/news/" title="View all posts in News">News</a> <a class="feedcat" href="http://crippslawtest.co.uk/category/press-coverage/" title="View all posts in Press Coverage">Press Coverage</a> <a class="feedcat" href="http://crippslawtest.co.uk/category/reports/" title="View all posts in Reports">Reports</a>
<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="http://crippslawtest.co.uk/top-25-law-firms/">Cripps named one of Top 25  law firms in UK</a>
</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed luctus, metus non mattis pretium, felis diam vehicula leo, ac condimentum orci mi sit amet nisl. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque pellentesque dui ac facilisis varius. Morbi porta luctus arcu, id vulputate dui pellentesque et. Sed eget nunc sit amet elit euismod auctor et ut nibh. Nullam in [&hellip;]</p>
```

I have just roughly copied your source code. 
But the main idea is to add the image after the "p" tag and adding styling.

Comment: Hi Manu, I tried your solution in my php loop by adding  CrippsTheme_post_thumbnail(); after my p date tag but it didn't work :( Thanks for your response though.